# Scala how to apply a function in the caller stack

Tags: scala, logging, macros, logback

I am using "`LazyLogging`" and configured the "`logback`" to print the class and line number of the print statement.

I want to create a small wrapper function in my code that prints some context along with the regular message. But since the actual "caller" of the log function is inside this new wrapper function, I am losing my class and line number of the true print statement.

For instance:

```
class Foo(context: Context) extends LazyLogging {
...
...
logger.info("some message") // assume this is line "41"
...
...
}
```

the resulting console log looks like:

```
14:40:39 INFO  [Foo:41] some message
```

But lets say I create a small wrapper that should print the "context" with each log statement:

```
class Foo(context: Context) extends LazyLogging {
...
...
def logWithContext(msg: String) = logger.info(s"[$context] $msg") // assume this is line 5
...
...
logWithContext("some message") // assume this is line "41"
...
...
logWithContext("a different message") // assume this is line "51"
...
...
}
```

But now the resulting console always appears at line 5

```
14:40:39 INFO  [Foo:5] some message 
14:40:39 INFO  [Foo:5] a different message
```

I'm guessing that I need to return an "unapplied" function to the caller and apply in their context (on their line), or some other sort of macro (such as ones I would have done in old school C/C++ etc. capturing the caller's context)

Comment: I'm confused what your ultimate question is. Are you having trouble getting the context? Are you having trouble adding the context on a per-class basis?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you're going to be able to get the line number automatically since the bytecode will not contain that information.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you are looking for, but logback could potentially rescue you via the, somewaht unwieldy  [`caller{depth}`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#caller)

I have defined the logback conf:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} %caller{4} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and my code is:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

object Main extends App with LazyLogging {

  def lg(msg: String) = logger.info("prefix + " + msg)

  lg("1")

  lg("2")

}
```

and the result is:

```
270  [main] INFO  lg.Main$ Caller+0  at lg.Main$.lg(Main.scala:7)
Caller+1     at lg.Main$.delayedEndpoint$lg$Main$1(Main.scala:9)
Caller+2     at lg.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:5)
Caller+3     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
 - prefix + 1 
273  [main] INFO  lg.Main$ Caller+0  at lg.Main$.lg(Main.scala:7)
Caller+1     at lg.Main$.delayedEndpoint$lg$Main$1(Main.scala:11)
Caller+2     at lg.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:5)
Caller+3     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
 - prefix + 2
```

`Main.scala:9` and `Main.scala:11` differentiate the caller line